# can i create 2 blog 'feeds' within one blog

Tags: pages

Right now by blog has the 'home' section where all my new posts go, and 'pages' sections which are static pages that i can edit.

my question is, can i have another section that will behave like the 'home' link?

for example, can i have a page called 'cars' and a section called 'cats', where i can add new posts to either section?

if this is not possible, what are some workarounds?

**edit:**
i dont want the blog homepage to contains ALL stories, i want it to contain all stories under the cat category, and the 'car' page contain all the posts under 'car' category.

in essence, it will be like i have 2 different blogs under a single blog

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also create a custom feed and this to WP; use the function `add_feed()` for add a feed to WordPress and define the content inside the feed.

A example for feed with the drafts of WP can you read in [this post](http://wpengineer.com/424/feed-for-drafts-plugin/).

Answer (score 3):

You can use categories. Have a "Cats" category, and a "Cars" category.

Your main Blog Posts Index will show Posts in all categories by default, but your Category archive index pages will show only posts from the given category. So:

- `example.com`: all blog posts
- `example.com/category/cats/`: posts in the "Cats" category
- `example.com/category/cars/`: posts in the "Cars" category

And each category archive index page has its own feed, so you can have a "Cats" feed, and a "Cars" feed:

- `example.com/feed/`: feed for all blog posts
- `example.com/category/cats/feed/`: feed for the "Cats" category
- `example.com/category/cars/feed/`: feed for the "Cars" category

Comment: fair enough maybe my post wasnt specific. i dont want to have a feed for all blog posts, so going 'home' will give you either cats or cars.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to **combine** the *categories* solution with a *redirect plugin* to clean up the URL:

#### Let's say your page, "Bacon and Beans," has a blog and two podcasts, one on "Bacon" and one on "Beans":

```
example.com/category/blog/feed
example.com/category/podcast/feed
example.com/category/podcast/bacon/feed
example.com/category/podcast/beans/feed
```

You can use the [Quick Page/Post Redirect Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/quick-pagepost-redirect-plugin/) so that instead your users can type something more manageable and redirect to the desired feed:

#### Your blog feed:

```
example.com/blog    --> example.com/category/blog/feed
```

#### Your podcast feed:

```
example.com/podcast --> example.com/category/podcast/feed
```

#### Sub-feeds for your podcast:

```
example.com/bacon   --> example.com/category/podcast/bacon/feed
example.com/beans   --> example.com/category/podcast/beans/feed
```